# Get parent current state from child callback function | React

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, state

I'm trying to get `history` state from my callback function `onRestore` and when I log the history it's **logging only the history untill the id of the clicked snapshot**

 Why my callback function show incorrect state..

 I've already tried single thing I could so please help me

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react"
import Board from "./Board"
import Snapshot from "./Snapshot"



export default function Game(){
  const [ history, setHistory ] = useState([makeSnapshot(0, EMPTY_BOARD, true, onRestore)])
  const [ offset, setOffset ] = useState(0)

  function makeSnapshot(index, board, currentPlayer, onRestore){
    const snapshot = { index, board, currentPlayer, onRestore }
    return <Snapshot key={index} {...snapshot}/>
  }

  function onRestore(snapshot){
    console.log(snapshot) // #2 snapshot item
    console.log(history) // log only 2 snapshot items (if snapshot item id is #3 so 3 items in history)
  }

  function drawPlayer(index){
    const nextMove = makeSnapshot(history.length, newBoard, currentPlayer, onRestore)
    setHistory(prevHistory => ([...prevHistory, nextMove]))
    
    setOffset(history.length + 1)
  }



  return(
    <div className="Game">
      <h1>History: { history.map(snapshot => snapshot) } </h1>
    </div>
  )
}
```

```js
export default function Snapshot(snapshot){ 

  const move = !snapshot.index ? `game start` : `move #${snapshot.index}`
  const disableClass = snapshot.isDisabled ? " disabled" : ""

  return(
    <div id={snapshot.index} className="snapshot" onClick={() => snapshot.onRestore(snapshot)}> Go to {move} </div>
  )
}
```

[image]

Live log:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Store the data for each snapshot in state and use that to generate the JSX; do not store the JSX in state.

```
const [history, setHistory] = useState([{board: EMPTY_BOARD, currentPlayer: true}]);
// ...
return (
    <div className="Game">
        <h1>History: 
            { history.map((s, i) => <Snapshot key={i} {...s} index={i} onRestore={onRestore} />) }
        </h1>
    </div>
);
```

Comment: You're a life saver :)
I think I'll never do it again.. storing  jsx in state leading to strange behavior of the rest states